# Regarding HTTP 400 bad request

Tags: http

I have searched a lot but seems can't find the answer.

I'm studying the http request, I have tested below http request is working.

```
GET / HTTP/1.1

HOST: abc.go.com
```

But I want to put it in a single line, I had tried below but it just doesn't work, the response is HTTP 400, bad request, what should I use instead?

```
GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: abc.go.com\r\n\r\n
```

Comment: Is there a reason why it has to be on one line?

Comment: Please tag all your programming questions with the programming language you are using (even if you think it couldn't _possibly_ be relevant, because, like, _obviously_ all programming languages in the known _universe_ must interpret strings in the same way). /sarcasm

Answer (score 1):

A likely problem is that your scripting or programming language is interpreting `\n` and `\r`  as literally `\n` and `\r`, not as the special characters they represent.  Without knowing what language you're using, precise help is difficult.  If it's PHP, make sure that you use `"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: abc.go.com\r\n\r\n"`, not `'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: abc.go.com\r\n\r\n'`.